# Projective Maps

Tags: projective-geometry

> A projective map is a function which preserves cross-ratio. So consider a circle $\Gamma$ and a point $P$ not necessarily on $\Gamma$. Will the function which maps $\Gamma$ to the pencil of lines going through $P$ via $X \mapsto PX$ be projective?

I think it should. Consider any  4 points $A, B, C, D$. Let $\gamma_{ABCD}$ be the conic which passes through $A, B, C, D, P$. Then the cross ratio will be preserved, since the map from a conic to a pencil of lines going through a point $P$ on the conic via $X \mapsto PX$ is projective.

Is this true?

Comment: How do you define this function for points not on $\Gamma$?

Comment: @brainjam I am defining a projective map with domain $\Gamma$ and range as the pencil of lines, I am NOT considering the whole plane

Comment: Cross ratio is only defined for collinear points.  If $A,B,C,D$ are on $\Gamma$ they are not collinear.  So how are you defining cross ratio on $\Gamma$?

Comment: @brainjam see: https://math.mit.edu/~notzeb/cross.pdf, section 1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a conic $\omega$ let $(A,B;C,D)_\omega$ be the cross ratio of $A,B,C,D$ with respect to $\omega$, defined as $(EA,EB;EC,ED)$ for any point $E$ on $\omega$ (it is the same for all $E$ on $\omega$, see [math.mit.edu/~notzeb/cross.pdf](http://math.mit.edu/~notzeb/cross.pdf), Definition 5).

Let $\gamma$ be the conic which passes through $A,B,C,D,P$.  Unless $P$ is on $\Gamma$ (in which case $\gamma=\Gamma$), $(A,B;C,D)_\gamma \ne (A,B;C,D)_\Gamma$.  But this means that in general the function $X \mapsto XP$ does not preserve cross ratio, and is not projective, because $(AP,BP;CP,DP)=(A,B;C,D)_\gamma$.

By way of context, we can define a conic as the locus of points $E$ such that $(EA,EB;EC,ED)=k$, where $A,B,C,D$ are four points in the plane such that no three of them are collinear and $k$ is a nonzero real.  When the four points are fixed and $k$ varies, we obtain the whole family of nondegenerate conics passing through the four points (I'm paraphrasing [Berger](https://books.google.ca/books?id=pN0iAVavPR8C&pg=PA201&lpg=PA201#v=onepage&q&f=false), bottom of page 201).  Conics $\Gamma$ and $\gamma$, as defined earlier, correspond to different values of $k$, unless $P$ is on $\Gamma$.

The OP asks whether their argument that the function is projective is correct.  It is true that the map from a conic $\omega$ to a pencil of lines going through a point $P$ on $\omega$ via $X \mapsto PX$ is projective.  But this assumes that the cross ratio being used is $(\dots)_{\omega}$.  But I think the original assertion is asking whether the function is preserving the cross ratio $(\dots)_{\Omega}$ with respect to the circle.